# DoubleClick on a row in JfaceTable to get the details of object on that row

Tags: swt, jface, e4

In eclipse e4.

On double clicking on a row in jface table I want to see the data on that row as a dialog.

**Existing Code**

```
orgTable.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Double CLikc works");
        }
    });
```

Comment: When down voting atleast leave a comment so that I can make sure I dont make same mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
OrgTable.addDoubleClickListener(new IDoubleClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void doubleClick(DoubleClickEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Double CLikc works");
            IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) event.getSelection();
            OrgDetails org = (OrgDetails) sel.getFirstElement();
            if(org != null){
                System.out.println("Double-click on : "+ org.getOrgName()+ " " + org.getTin());
            }
            System.out.println(orgTable.getElementAt());
        }
    });
```